# How to establish Asynchronous Process in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, jquery

I am using MVC3 and Entity Framework.

In my project, I have a view and a controller. From my view I am importing 1000 records from excel to the database and that works fine.

My requirement is, while inserting large rows of data to the database I need to indicate
the status of the importing rows and the % of loading completed and need to add background process( thread)..
How to achieve this one? Need Help on this.

View Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FImport", "Import", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    //Here i'm Inserting 1000 of records using table
    <input type="submit" value="Start Import" /></td>
}
```

Controller Code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FImport(FormCollection collection)
{
}
```

How to do that?

Comment: Maybe AsyncController is what are you looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561610/is-a-background-worker-in-a-controller-async

Comment: no its not, i expected... @XarisFytrakis